# What is a function equivalent of source in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have a series of Tcl scripts which are being executed in an interpreter (Cadence Innovus). I want a way to group commands and execute them with a single call. Functionally I can achieve this by writing each group of commands in a separate file and calling `source <group_file_name>`. However it is inconvenient to define so many files.

I have tried to do this with:

```
proc {} {
    commands...
}
```

This doesn't give me the functionality I need though. I believe it executes the commands in a lower namespace and the variables that are set do not remain.

Is there a way to get this functionality (a single file with callable functions), but that execute in the same namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always use `uplevel` or `namespace eval` inside that procedure to change the current namespace. If you use `uplevel`, you would do this:

```
proc foo {} {
    uplevel 1 {
        TheFirstCommand
        TheSecondCommand
        TheThirdCommand
    }
}
```

With `namespace eval`, you might instead do this:

```
proc foo {} {
    namespace eval ::theTargetNamespace {
        TheFirstCommand
        TheSecondCommand
        TheThirdCommand
    }
}
```

Things get a bit more complicated if you're wanting to use local variables with the scope-changers, but the principle for how to manage things is about the same whichever mechanism you use.

```
proc foo {} {
    set a [uplevel 1 { TheFirstCommand }]
    set b [uplevel 1 { TheSecondCommand }]
    # Dynamically-generate the script to run; it's trivial code generation
    uplevel 1 [list TheThirdCommand $a $b]
}
```

Switching to `namespace eval` is pretty much a drop-in replacement.